# What is the right way to configure multiple pages in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to create a basic website using just Webpack. My purpose is to have a simple URL structure like example.com/about, example.com/contact.

In Webpack, I can use HTMLWebpackPlugin, but I need to create an instance for every route. So, my question is: is there a way to simplify this?

```js
const path = require('path');
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 5000,
    },
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Home',
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './src/pages/home/index.html',
        }),
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'About',
            filename: 'about/index.html',
            template: './src/pages/about/index.html',
        }),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You Webpack config file is javascript. So you could add some helper functions to abstract the process and eventually just plug in an array of pages that will produce the desired effect:

```js
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const generateHtmlPlugin = (title) => {
  return new htmlWebpackPlugin({
    title,
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: `./src/pages/${title.toLowerCase()}/index.html`,
  });
}

const populateHtmlPlugins = (pagesArray) => {
  res = [];
  pagesArray.forEach(page => {
    res.push(generateHtmlPlugin(page));
  })
  return res;
}
```

So this is not too much code, and it will allow you to just insert an array of your desired pages when setting up webpack:

```js
const pages = populateHtmlPlugins(["About", "Articles", "Users", "Contact"]);

module.exports = {
  //...
  plugins: pages
}
```

Better yet, you can create a `utils` folder and refactor the code into two exported modules, then just import `populateHtmlPlugins()` in your webpack config file and stay very clean.

Now you can create as many pages as you want easily enough.

Comment: config multi pages, how can we access the page in brower during dev?

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 can be used new [html-bundler-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin).
Using this plugin, the entry point is an HTML template where should be loaded all source scripts and styles.

You can easily define multiple HTML templates directly in Webpack entry, for example:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
  },

  entry: {
    // define HTML templates here
    index: './src/pages/home/index.html',  // => dist/index.html
    'about/index': './src/pages/about/index.html', // => dist/about/index.html
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      js: {
        // output filename of extracted JS from source script loaded in HTML via `<script>` tag
        filename: 'assets/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // output filename of extracted CSS from source style loaded in HTML via `<link>` tag
        filename: 'assets/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
      },
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: HtmlBundlerPlugin.loader, // HTML loader
      },
      // styles
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      // images
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|ico)/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'assets/img/[name].[hash:8][ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  // enable HMR with live reload
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    watchFiles: {
      paths: ['src/**/*.*'],
      options: {
        usePolling: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Or you can generate a Webpack entry like in the answer above.

For example, *index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <!-- load source style in HTML, not import in JavaScript -->
    <link href="./style.scss" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- load source script in HTML, not in Webpack entry -->
    <script src="./main.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <!-- load source image -->
    <img src="./image.png">
</body>
</html>
```

The generated HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="assets/css/style.f57966f4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/js/main.b855d8f4.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <img src="assets/img/image.d2f4b855.png">
</body>
</html>
```

The HtmlBundlerPlugin plugin replaces the most used functionality of the html-webpack-plugin and mini-css-extract-plugin plugins.